# Get the body text from https.request

Tags: node.js

I've this example from  [here](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback)

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET'
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
req.end();
```

In the `https.request` response how to get the body (html) of the response. I mean which property to use in d object in `process.stdout.write(d);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example given above, **process.stdout.write(d)** writes the response body to the console. If you want to use **console.log()**, you can use it as given bellow,

```
 res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
    console.log(d.toString('utf8'));
  });
```

**d.toString('utf8')** is required as **d** is a buffer variable and is required to be converted to **utf8** string.

> d.toString('utf8')

The above converts buffer to string.